# Why do I see 0v on electret microphones?

Tags: microphone

I've got a few electret microphones and I tried to make this circuit:

[image]

It didn't amplify my sound, it continuously buzzed. Without mic it did same thing. So I probed mic and I saw 0.000v. Also 0mA (shorted).

I tested 5 microphones sitting next to each other, they all had same results. There was a neodymium magnet about 3-4cm next to them. Are they broken? Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that schematic?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious or mystical I can't see how that circuit would ever work.

Comment: @Marla Google images :/ is it normal for the microphones to show 0mV and 0mA?

Comment: I just viewed the "circuits today" article.  The circuit is for a carbon microphone.

Comment: @Marla oh, my bad.. thanks! would you like to post it with answer to voltage and ampere question so I can approve it?

Comment: Holy crap, that schematic is a real blast from the past. The HEP230 is an old Motorola germanium power transistor -- it probably hasn't been made since at least the 1980s. Completely obsolete.

Comment: @duskwuff Now that you mention it, that is old! I remember when carbon mikes were common (I even made one of my own following an article back in the 60's.) [I now have a huge collection of ancient germanium transistors. Some store just "dumped" their ancient (dusty, but new) stock a few years back and I picked up a lot of whatever they had in germanium. No idea why I did that. Now I need to construct a museum or something just to house the things. Chances are I've got some HEP230s. But it's boxed up for now. So I won't look today.]

Comment: @jonk Might be worth digging out. Some germanium transistors are in high demand for guitar effects.

Comment: @duskwuff Seriously? I'll have to make a list sometime and see what the market is doing. Many of these are in original boxes, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electret microphones have an internal amplifier that requires a bias voltage at a few mA (or less) current; they have a moderately high impedance. Carbon button microphones are much lower impedance. Note that though a carbon mic is nonpolarized, i.e. it doesn't matter which way it's connected, electrets may require connection of a specific line to positive. Some electrets have a three-wire connection, one for ground, one for V+ and a third for output.

The schematic below should work with most two-terminal electret mics to drive a standard mic input on a PA, but you'd need high-impedance headphones or anther stage of amplification to drive a speaker.

[image: Electret mic amp]
*from http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/instruments-and-amps/188392-buffer-preamp-circuit-electret-mic.html, modified*